# Azure Node.js backend Webapp redis-connect error 500?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure-web-app-service

I've setup a ReactJS webapp on Microsoft Azure, I have a Front End web app and a Back end webapp. When I try to log onto the Front end app, it sends a POST request to my backend app API endpoint. I know the issue is to do with the connect-reddis module as seen below. I've tried consulting ChatGPT but for the first time ChatGPT can't solve this problem, however it did give me a temporary solution which is setting the session to null then only change the value once a the user is logged in, this made the login POST request work, but no requests for Getting or Posting data for the dashboard worked consequently. Pretty sure the issue lies in my api.js file (On my backend I have api.js, server.js and database.js, on my front end I have a Login.js file then it navigates to a dashboard.js file).

Error message on Azure log stream suggests the error is in line 6 where RedisStore is defined:

> Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:TypeError: require(...) is not a functionat Object.<anonymous>

Here is my api.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('./database');
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

// Redis client configuration
const client = redis.createClient({
  url: '<redacted for security>',
  port: 6380,
  password: '<redacted for security>',
  tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Redis error: ', err);
});

// Middleware to check if a user is authenticated
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.username) {
        next();
    } else {
        // User is not authenticated, respond with 401 status
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not logged in.' });
    }
}

// Setup session middleware
router.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: client }),
  secret: 'Your_Secret_Key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = await db.getUser(username, password);
  if(user) {
    req.session.username = username;
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User logged in successfully.' });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid username or password.' });
  }
});

router.get('/get-promises', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const senusername = req.session.username;
  try {
    const promises = await db.getAllPromises(senusername); // pass senusername as parameter
    return res.status(200).json(promises);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving promises.' });
  }
});

router.post('/add-promise', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const { promise, recusername, sentAt } = req.body;
  const senusername = req.session.username;
  const status = 'active';

  try {
    await db.addPromise(promise, status, recusername, senusername, sentAt);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Promise added successfully.' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error adding the promise.' });
  }
});

router.put('/update-promise/:id', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { status } = req.body;

  try {
    await db.updatePromiseStatus(id, status);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Promise status updated successfully.' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error updating the promise status.' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Tried this code, recieved error relating to memorystore not being a valid method.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('./database');
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
let RedisStore = null;

// Redis client configuration
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: '<redacted for security>',
  port: 6380,
  password: '<redacted for security>',
  tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Redis error: ', err);
});

// Middleware to check if a user is authenticated
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.username) {
        next();
    } else {
        // User is not authenticated, respond with 401 status
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not logged in.' });
    }
}

// Setup session middleware
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session) {
        RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
    }
    
    session({
        store: RedisStore ? new RedisStore({ client: client }) : undefined,
        secret: 'Your_Secret_Key',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    })(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = await db.getUser(username, password);
  if(user) {
    req.session.username = username;
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User logged in successfully.' });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid username or password.' });
  }
});

router.get('/get-promises', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const senusername = req.session.username;
  try {
    const promises = await db.getAllPromises(senusername); // pass senusername as parameter
    return res.status(200).json(promises);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving promises.' });
  }
});

router.post('/add-promise', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const { promise, recusername, sentAt } = req.body;
  const senusername = req.session.username;
  const status = 'active';

  try {
    await db.addPromise(promise, status, recusername, senusername, sentAt);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Promise added successfully.' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error adding the promise.' });
  }
});

router.put('/update-promise/:id', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { status } = req.body;

  try {
    await db.updatePromiseStatus(id, status);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Promise status updated successfully.' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error updating the promise status.' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could please tell are you able to connect to Radis local? are you also deploying to Azure as well? 500 response is local or in Azure

Comment: @Sampath It did work locally but I used express session, now since I've deployed to azure from github ci/cd I've had to change to reddis-connect. 500 response is in azure (can be seen on promisestat.azurewebsites.net, try to login with username and password 1)

Comment: using azure radius right

Comment: @Sampath azure reddis yes. This is my url and my password is the primary access key in my azure reddis resource

redis://promisestat.redis.cache.windows.net:6380

Comment: I can see you are /login what type of login u are using

Comment: @Sampath I got it to work by downgrading to redis version 6. Now when I send a POST request from Insomnia I get a timeout error? Says it connected to redis properly, connected to the sql server properly, don't know why it is timing out. Can you help?

Comment: you are connecting the with password in Redis which will be in the access key as the primary key. for SQL server try to connect with connection string

Comment: @jock Locke ```const connectionString = "your_connection_string_here";

const redisClient = new Redis(connectionString, {
  tls: {
    servername: "your_redis_host"
  }
});

redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
redisClient.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected to redis successfully');
});```

Comment: refer to this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/azure-redis-timeouts-client-side-issues/ba-p/2022203)    and sql refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381052/azure-sql-connections-are-timing-out)

Comment: - For SQL server refer to this  [links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql-db) , [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447498/recurring-timeout-on-sql-azure)  ,[link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-query-timeouts)  and  [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743725/how-to-troubleshoot-intermittent-sql-timeout-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The errror you encourted in Azure Node.js Webapp  [Redis Cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/969454/connection-error-on-console-screen-of-redis-cache-azure#:%7E:text=As%20answered%20here%2C%20it%27s%20a%20firewall%20restriction.%20The,public%20IP%20%28needs%20to%20be%20visible%20to%20Azure%29.)  is server error.

```js
const  express = require('express');
const  session = require('express-session');
const  Redis = require('ioredis');  
const  connectRedis = require('connect-redis');
var  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const  app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({  extended:  true  }));
app.set('trust proxy',  1);
const  redisClient = new  Redis({
host:  'sampath123.redis.cache.windows.net',
port:  6380,
password:  'nNtaFzuZp8ZdxO1nxQfdwCkMuw3x46=',
tls:  {  servername:  'sampath123.redis.cache.windows.net'  }
});
redisClient.on('error',  function  (err)  {
console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
redisClient.on('connect',  function  (err)  {
console.log('Connected to redis successfully');
});
const  RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
app.use(session({
store:  new  RedisStore({  client:  redisClient  }),
secret:  'secret$%^134',
resave:  false,
saveUninitialized:  false,
cookie:  {
secure:  false,
httpOnly:  false,
maxAge:  1000 * 60 * 10
}
}));
app.get("/",  (req,  res)  =>  {
const  sess = req.session;
if (sess.username && sess.password) {
if (sess.username) {
res.write(`<h1>Welcome ${sess.username} </h1><br>`);
res.write(`<h3>This is the Home page</h3>`);
res.end('<a href=' + '/logout' + '>Click here to log out</a >');
}
}  else  {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
}
});
app.post("/login",  (req,  res)  =>  {
const  sess = req.session;
const  {  username,  password  } = req.body;
sess.username = username;
sess.password = password;
res.end("success");
});
app.get("/logout",  (req,  res)  =>  {
req.session.destroy(err  =>  {
if (err) {
return  console.log(err);
}
res.redirect("/");
});
});
app.listen(7000,  ()  =>  {
console.log("Server started at port 7000");
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- For SQL server refer to this  [links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql-db) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743725/how-to-troubleshoot-intermittent-sql-timeout-errors)

```
const redisClient = new  Redis(connectionString, { tls: {
 servername: "your_redis_host" }
  });
   redisClient.on('error', function (err) { console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err); 
   }); 
redisClient.on('connect', function () 
{ console.log('Connected to redis successfully');
 });
```